# Manipulate DOM in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to learn about chrome extensions but I am not able to understand how to manipulate `DOM` of a page using `content_scripts`.

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "First",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "First extension",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["test.js"]
    },

    "page_action": {

        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "content_scripts": [ {
        "js": [ "jquery.min.js", "popup1.js"  ],
        "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ]

    } ],

    "permissions" : [
        "tabs",
        "http://*/*"
            ]
}
```

**test.js**

```
function check(tab_id, data, tab){

    if(tab.url.indexOf("google") > -1){
        chrome.pageAction.show(tab_id);
            }

};
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(check);
```

**popup1.js**

```
function myfunc(){

    var x = $('#options option:selected').text();
    $("body").append('Test');
    alert(x);
    //window.close();

}

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#options').change(myfunc);

});
```

The above code/extension works fine because `myfunc` gets called but it doesn't inject `Test` into the body of `google.com`.

So, where am I going wrong in accessing/manipulating the DOM.

Comment: First, you do not need to bind to `ready`, because your content script is executed at `document_idle` (default), which is guaranteed to happen after the DOM is ready. Second, please provide more info on what you see in `myfunc`: either you possibly have some errors in console, or you did overlook the added text in the body. I'm not sure, wouldn't it be `$("body").append(document.createTextNode("Test"));`?

Comment: BTW, how do you check the body, if you close the window just after the appending?

Comment: Also I'd like to make sure that you do not load `popup1.js` into popup.html and trying to accomplish some tricks with `popup1.js` being a part of a web-page and your popup window at the same time. What are your requirements? Why do you name content script "popup"?

Comment: @Stan: What I am trying to achieve is whenever change event is fired from dropdown list `TEST` is appended to the body of `google.com`. Currently what is happening is `TEST` in inject into my `popup.html` which appears when I click on the page_action icon. Here is my [popup.html](http://sprunge.us/FHBJ)

Comment: Why do you use a "popup"? You should not use "popup" at all for this purpose. Don't mix a script in your popup (if you need it for some other tasks) and the content script, injected into external web-pages.

Comment: @Stan: The reason I use a popup(dropdown) is I want my user to select a value and based on that value I want to perform some DOM manipulation. So, I think I need a pop-up.

Comment: That's not a problem, but you should decide which is the purpose of the script which you name `popup1.js` at the moment. If it's a content script, than exclude it from the popup.html and check other points I mentioned above.

Comment: @Stan:Currently the purpose of `popup1.js` is to manipulate the DOM of `google.com` or anyother link using the value selected from the drop-down but it is not appending anything to the body tag even when I remove it from `content_scripts`. If I remove `popup1.js` from `popup.html` than my script doesn't get called and nothing happens. So, my simple question is what is the easiest way to maniulate DOM in chrome extension.

Comment: Your code looks ok, and it should work, especially taking into account that you confirmed that almost the same code from answer below works ok. You did not answer if you try `document.createTextNode`. Also, as I wrote, don't use `ready`, just bind `$('#options').change(myfunc);`.

Comment: So, I tried both of your suggestion and now my modified `popup1.js` looks like [this](http://sprunge.us/dUTO). Now, `myfunc` function doesn't even get called and now nothing happens. The below mentioned code does work but as I wrote that as soon as I add `event listerner` code it stops working.

Comment: I tried your code in a simple html file and everything works fine. What I think is happening in your case is that once you select a value   from drop-down the focus gets shifted to the `popup(popup.html)` and all DOM manipulations happens wrt the popup.html.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to play with browser tab DOM on event of popup. In this case you have to pass a message to `content script` from `background script`, or `inject JavaScript` into `content script` : have a look

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "First",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "First extension",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["test.js"]
    },    
    "page_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },    
    "content_scripts": [ {
        "js": [ "jquery.min.js", "content_script.js"  ],
        "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ]    
    } ],

    "permissions" : [
        "tabs",
        "http://*/*"
            ]
}
```

content_script.js

```
function myfunc(){
    var x = $('#options option:selected').text();
    $("body").append('<div style="width:200px; height:200px; border: 1px solid red;"></div>');
}

$(document).ready(myfunc);
```

Now you will get `A box with red border` at the bottom of the page.

**popup.js**

```
function myfunc(){
    var x = $('#options option:selected').text();
    chrome.extension.sendMessage({sel_text: x});
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#options').change(myfunc);
});
```

**test.js (used in background)**

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    appendTextToBody(request.sel_text);
  });

function appendTextToBody(text) {
  chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {"code" : '$("body").append("Test : "'+text+');'}) ;
  });
}

function check(tab_id, data, tab){
    if(tab.url.indexOf("google") > -1){
        chrome.pageAction.show(tab_id);
    }
};
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(check);
```

Comment: Your code works fine. But I need to add an event listener to look for change in drop-down list selected value. Therefore as soon as I add `$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#options').change(myfunc);


});` keeping rest all the same the above code doesn't work.

Comment: I have updated my answer, take a look and tell me, if there is something wrong .. thanks

Comment: Thanks for the updated code. I tried but it is still not appending anything to the page html. I tried debugging and found that `appendTextToBody` is getting called and the value of `text` is also as required but `chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {"code" : '$("body").append("Test : "'+text+');'}) ;`is not working as required.

Comment: may be there JQuery is not exist, try this one :  `chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {"code" : 'var my_span = document.createElement('span'); my_span.innerHTML("Test : "); document.body.appendChild(my_span)'});` instead of `$("body").append("Test : "'+text+');`

Comment: Now, this is really strange I tried the simplest of code `chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {"code" : "alert('hello')"}) ;` and it is not working. It is late night now, so I will give it a try again in the morning and get back to you. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Noob: If u see that by default `google` now uses `https`. So, try adding `"https://*/"` in `permissions` inside  `manifest.json`.